# KOTLIN not Java! How to use maketoast within a fragment (or make a click work in a fragment)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, toast

Hi I've been having issue with making a click work in a fragment. (e.g. Toast, button, or anything related to click)

For instance, I'm trying to implement Toast.makeText in the code below.
xml file mentioned in this code is an image gallery and I want my app to display a toast for each image to show what the image is about.

I've been trying many different things and have been searching for 10 hourish, but nothing seemed to work. Plus, most sources related to this question were for Java only. Any help or suggestion will very much be appreciated.

```
class GalleryFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    var myButton: ImageView? = null
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val myView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false)
        myButton = myView.findViewById<View>(R.id.image1) as ImageView
        myButton!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        return myView
    }
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, "Beach", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: First, in this case, there's no difference between java and kotlin. Your code looks ok, just check if your `onClick` is called or not. (using logs or breakpoints).

Comment: @momt99 That's the thing. I think `onClick` is being called based on what I see from the logcat. `Toast.makeText` seems to be the problem in my case.

Comment: Try logging something in the `onClick` function and see if it appears in LogCat.

Comment: I tried to run your code and it's working without any problem. I think the problem is elsewhere. Check your activity and/or application class code. Also, make sure the context this fragment is running on is properly configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks Ok.

Please check if the image on which you are expecting the click to show a toast is not too small that it is not physically clickable. maybe you have the image view of the size 16dp or even less. Or you may have set the `android:clickable` to `false`.

If you could add the layout file, it would be easier to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From fragments this is how I generate Toasts (with either requireActivity() or requireContext()).  You might also want to move the attaching of the listener to onViewCreated():

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    myButton = myView.findViewById<View>(R.id.image1) as ImageView
    myButton!!.setOnClickListener(this)
}

override fun onClick(v: View) {
    //here is the change
    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Beach", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

You could also create an extension function:

```
fun Context.shortToast(toastMessage: String){
    Toast.makeText(this, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()
}
 //call this in the fragment
requireContext().shortToast("Here is my toast message")
```

Answer (score 0):

if **onClick** you checked it and it is tiggered, change where it sais: `activity?.applicationContext` with `v.context` and tell me if that works. Maybe you are getting wrong context.

Answer (score 0):

The context should not be nullable type. The error shows that it is a type mismatch.

```
  Toast.makeText(context, "saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

The !! (not-null assertion operator) is used to denote the variable is not null.
Using let and safe calls

```
 context?.let{ context->
            Toast.makeText(context, "saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```